# Axios throws an error even, if received a proper response. How to stop it?

Tags: json, api, vue.js, .net-core, axios

i have a .Net Core 3.1 Api, and a client application which communicates with my API using axios. I have defined following endpoint:

```
        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<UserDto>> LoginUserAsync([FromBody] LoginRequest loginRequest)
        {
            try
            {
                var user = await QueryBus
                    .SendAsync<LoginQuery, UserDto>(new LoginQuery
                {
                    Login = loginRequest.Login,
                    Password = loginRequest.Password
                });

                return user != null
                    ? (ActionResult<UserDto>) Ok(user)
                    : Unauthorized();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                    new { e.Message });
            }
        }
```

The endpoint works properly, and it returns authenticated user. The problem is while axios is trying to parse my response. Here's my method responsible for communication:

```
  async post(resource, data, handleError = true) {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
      },
    };
    try {
      const result = await api.post(resource, data, config);
      return result;
    } catch (ex) {
      if (handleError) {
        if (ex.response.data && ex.response.data.message) {
          vm.$snotify.error(ex.response.data.message);
        } else {
          vm.$snotify.error(ex.message);
        }
      }
      throw ex;
    }
  },
```

Although, my api prepares a correct response, the code on the client side hits the catch block. I've tried to debug the method so i have attached console.log to my catch block as shown below:

```
    catch (ex) {
      console.log(ex);
      if (handleError) {
        if (ex.response.data && ex.response.data.message) {
          vm.$snotify.error(ex.response.data.message);
        } else {
          vm.$snotify.error(ex.message);
        }
      }
      throw ex;
    }
```

The behaviour of my function is very strange to me because a following object is being logged to the browser console:
[image]

It looks like instead of having an error in the ex variable i have my response which i should have received from axios. Even response, prepared by my api is stored in data section. This behavior is very strange for me. What am i doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: what is `api` in `api.post`? Where are you calling `axios`?

Comment: @devcrp this is api:const api =                                                                   axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL,
});